# "Home Screen" like effect while switching between views on Android

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, homescreen

I'm creating an application on android similar to that of a book. I would simply like to have the scrolling effect between views (not activities) similar to that of the home screen. Currently I am using a `ViewFlipper` and don't have the animation I would like, since the shift is sudden as opposed to following your finger.

I am aware that there are several opensource projects and classes being developed to achieve such a thing more easily for the individual programmer, but wondered if there was a way I may have overlooked to implement a homescreen-esque effect. An alternative which I have thought of using would be a `TabView`, with no label tabs being displayed above the content of the page, yet have not heavily looked into this option yet.

If anyone has encountered the same hurdle and has any ideas of how to overcome it, I will buy you a pizza! (Not really... I don't know your address) But I'd be very appreciative! :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`ViewPager`](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html). It's part of the compatibility library.

Comment: Is that compatable on android as far back as 2.2? I know it was only made recently.

Comment: From the link: ViewPager was released as part of the Compatibility Package revision 3 and works with Android 1.6 upwards.